# RxJava PublishSubject Not being Executed onNext

Tags: android, android-viewpager, rx-java, android-adapter, publishsubject

Can anyone point me to the right direction please? I have a RecyclerView which holds a ViewPager who has 2 Fragments.
So the view hierarchy kinda looks like these:

```
Activity
-------RecyclerView
------------------Adapter ↖
------------------------ViewPager ↖
---------------------------------Fragment1 (Radio Buttons) , Fragment2 (Num Picker)
```

Im trying to retrieve a Click on each Radio Button (Enum Long Value) so I modify Room DB inside the Adapter.

**Gif of Use Case:**

[image: Gif]

This is my **Open Fragment1** code:

```
private val publishSubject: PublishSubject<Long> = PublishSubject.create()
open val publishObservable: Observable<Long> = publishSubject

RadioButton.onClick { _ -> 
    publishSubject.onNext(WINNER.AWAY.value) 
    println("Fragment 1 = ${WINNER.AWAY.value}") // <-- This prints on Click
}

enum class WINNER(val value: Long) {
        LOCAL(1),
        DRAW(2),
        AWAY(3)
}
```

In the **Adapter**:

```
val fragment1 = Fragment1()
mDisposable.add(fragment1.publishObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe { println("Adapter = $it") }) // <-- This doesnt println
```

I have tried using Bundles, Shared Preferences, Interfaces and even other Horizontal RecyclerView (This one Im not sure how to rlly use with a fixed view)But i do know performance wise RV its better.

Comment: See what PublishSubject.hasObservers returns in your click handler. If false, your adapter code setting up the observation has not run. Also you don't need subscribeOn as it has no practical effect on PublishSubject.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @akarnokd. Indeed its returning false. Added `.doOnSubscribe { value -> Log.i(TAG, "SUBSCRIBE $value") }` **= SUBSCRIBE false**. I decided to start a chain all the way from front and moved the adapter code to the Fragment holding the *RV* with same result. Tried calling it from the main Activity with same result. Will try with Arch Components VM and LiveData.

Comment: Printing a `Disposable` of `doOnSubscribe` has little to no practical value and is not related to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input sir. On a side note, ViewModel and LiveData seem to fix the issue.